# How can I interpret the below GJR-GARCH model in terms of "leverage effects"?

Tags: interpretation, garch, finance

I'm very new here and am struggling to interpret the model. Please help me in layman's terms.

```py
                            AR - GJR-GARCH Model Results                            
====================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                           GD   R-squared:                      -0.003
Mean Model:                              AR   Adj. R-squared:                 -0.004
Vol Model:                        GJR-GARCH   Log-Likelihood:               -3572.12
Distribution:      Standardized Student's t   AIC:                           7168.24
Method:                  Maximum Likelihood   BIC:                           7236.93
                                              No. Observations:                 2261
Date:                      Sat, Apr 15 2023   Df Residuals:                     2257
Time:                              07:18:04   Df Model:                            4
                                  Mean Model                                 
=============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|       95.0% Conf. Int.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Const          0.0688  2.281e-02      3.017  2.555e-03    [2.411e-02,  0.114]
GD[1]         -0.0134  2.114e-02     -0.635      0.526 [-5.485e-02,2.801e-02]
GD[2]         -0.0327  2.011e-02     -1.626      0.104 [-7.210e-02,6.716e-03]
GD[3]      6.0716e-03  1.971e-02      0.308      0.758 [-3.255e-02,4.470e-02]
                               Volatility Model                              
=============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|       95.0% Conf. Int.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
omega          0.1078  4.361e-02      2.473  1.341e-02    [2.236e-02,  0.193]
alpha[1]       0.0322  1.903e-02      1.691  9.074e-02 [-5.108e-03,6.947e-02]
alpha[2]   4.1672e-14  1.602e-02  2.602e-12      1.000 [-3.139e-02,3.139e-02]
gamma[1]       0.0394  2.891e-02      1.364      0.172 [-1.722e-02,9.611e-02]
gamma[2]       0.1528  3.636e-02      4.202  2.651e-05    [8.151e-02,  0.224]
beta[1]    9.4508e-03  4.481e-02      0.211      0.833 [-7.837e-02,9.727e-02]
beta[2]        0.7992  5.555e-02     14.386  6.313e-47      [  0.690,  0.908]
                              Distribution                              
========================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|  95.0% Conf. Int.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
nu             5.2877      0.574      9.215  3.121e-20 [  4.163,  6.412]
========================================================================
```

I read so many articles or paper over the internet and I concluded below. But not sure if I'm right.

Here, the p-value for gamma[1] is 0.172(which is greater than 0.05), hence gamma[1] is not statistically significant, and we cannot conclude that there is a significant leverage effect.
However, the p-value for gamma[2] is less than 0.05, indicating that gamma[2] is statistically significant.
Therefore, we can conclude that the model has captured significant leverage effects.

Also, I want to write a generic code that includes all the scenarios like,

1. What if the gamma[1] is +ve and gamma[2] is -ve.
2. What if we have n the number of gammas in the model, in that case can I follow the same approach?
3. If we have n number of gammas, and they are in a combination of +ve and -ve, how we can conclude then?

Comment: For readability, text should ideally be posted as text, not as picture. You could post the output and format it as code (add \```python at the start and then \``` at the end), so that it retains the shape. Regarding the question, what have you tried so far? There are tons of material on GARCH models, including GJR-GARCH. What textbook, lecture note, academic article, blog post or software documentation are you following?

Comment: Thank you, Richard, I have edited the post and added the necessary details. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Thank you! The formatting is great now, and the question contains a decent amount of detail.

Answer (score 0):

According to [V-Lab](https://vlab.stern.nyu.edu/docs/volatility/GJR-GARCH), the conditional variance equation of a GJR-GARCH model (extended from one to two lags in an obvious way) is
$$
\sigma_t^2=\omega+(\alpha_1+\gamma_1 I_{t-1})\varepsilon_{t-1}^2+(\alpha_2+\gamma_1 I_{t-2})\varepsilon_{t-2}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-2}^2
$$
where $I_{t-j}=1$ if $\varepsilon_{t-j}<0$ and $I_{t-j}=0$ otherwise, for $j=1,2$. (You may want to check if Python uses the same representation. In the following, I will assume it does.) Now, you assume
$$
\sigma_t^2=\omega+(\alpha_1+ve I_{t-1})\varepsilon_{t-1}^2+(\alpha_2-ve I_{t-2})\varepsilon_{t-2}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-1}^2+\beta_1\sigma_{t-2}^2.
$$
The equation tells you how a shock $\varepsilon_t$ affects the conditional variance one and two periods ahead, $\sigma_{t+1}^2$ and $\sigma_{t+2}^2$. Just insert the specific value of the shock into the formula, and you readily get an answer. (You may need to shift the time index by 1 or 2 for each member of the equation, but that is straightforward.)

With $n$ $\gamma$s, the logic is still the same. I do not know what exactly we could conclude from that, but I find such a pattern of $\gamma$s unlikely to be observed in practice, so the question itself might not be all that relevant.

Comment: Hi Richard, I didn't understand "past shock has a certain additive impact on the conditional variance 1 step ahead and the exact opposite impact 2 steps ahead". Please explain. Also, is my interpretation above is correct?

Comment: @Rijia, I have edited my answer.